# Header and Footer Option missing in Microsoft Print to PDF / Printing Preferences / Page Layout

Tags: pdf, printing, microsoft, print-to-pdf

I was trying to print some txt files in PDF via 'Microsfot Print to PDF' and by default it prints the header and footer.

Reading about it online articles mention that I could remove them by unselecting those options in the Page Layout window which I get when choosing Printing preferences, but my popout window doesn't have those options.

Anyone knows how I could get those options back? Pretty sure they were there in the past (months ago). It barely has any option atm.

[image: Header and Footer Option missing in Microsoft Print to PDF / Printing Preferences / Page Layout]

Comment: Possible workaround: Some applications, such as Firefox, implement their own print to PDF process, with control of headers, simplified layout, etc. in the print dialog.

Comment: Thanks, managed to partially progress this time doing that now with Firefox but that forced me to remove both, headers and footers, I wanted to keep the footer but not the header if possible. 

Still wondering what has happened to all the options in those virtual PDF printers, they're totally gone :S